# IsEnabled button in datagrid mvvm wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

How to enable/disable button inside datagrid using mvvm, where column status equals some value in c#?

Thanks.

P.S. I'm new in mvvm and wpf.

**Edited:**

My code only prints data in Datagrid. I want to disable edit button when column status equals to 1.

You can see my code below.

**Model file**

```
public class Reestr
{
    private int id;
    private string date;
    private string market;
    private int status;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set {
            id = value;
        }
    }   
    public string Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set {
            date = value;
        }
    }
    public string Market
    {
        get { return market; }
        set {
            market = value;
        }
    }
    public int Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set {
            status = value;
        }
    } 
}
```

**ViewModel file**

```
public ReestrViewModel()
{
    reestr = GetListOfReestrs();
    reestr.Add(new Reestr() { Date = "01.08.2017", Market = "Market1", Status = 0 });
    reestr.Add(new Reestr() { Date = "02.08.2017", Market = "Market2", Status = 1 });
}
public ObservableCollection<Reestr> ReestrItems
{
    get { return reestr; }
}
public ObservableCollection<Reestr> GetListOfReestrs()
{
    return reestr;
}
```

**Xaml file:**

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="All"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          x:Name="ReestrDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ReestrViewModel.ReestrItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"
                            Binding="{Binding Id}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Visibility="Hidden"
                            Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date"
                            Binding="{Binding Date}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Market"
                            Binding="{Binding Market}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"
                            Binding="{Binding Status}"
                            IsReadOnly="True" 
                            Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Operations" Width="200">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="ViewButton"
                                Click="ViewButton_Click"></Button>
                        <Button x:Name="EditButton"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>               
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: How about you show us some of your xaml and code? What do you mean by column status, how should the viewmodel know about any columns?

Comment: Theoretically you should have a `Command` on your ViewModel that would be bound to your Button, said command needs to implement ICommand interface which also consists of CanExecute method. That CanExecute method will then be used to determine whether Button should be enabled or not.

Comment: @grek40, updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<Button x:Name="EditButton">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helped to me.

Comment: By the way, how can I set my custom style in this button? Cause I can't do something like this `<Button x:Name="EditButton" Style="MyCustomStyle">...</Button>`

Comment: <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyCustomStyle}">. But please ask another question if you have another issue.

Comment: Ok. Thanks this is what I was looking.